# Error handling in Net::Openssh (host ,async =>1) option

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am using Openssh module to connect to hosts using the (async => 1) option.
How is it possible to  trap connection errors for those hosts that are not able to connect.I do not want the error to appear in the terminal but instead be stored  in a data structure, since I want to finally format all the data as a cgi script.When I run the script the hosts that   has a connection problem throw error in the terminal.The code executes further and try to run commands on disconnected hosts.I want to isolate the disconnected hosts.

```
my (%ssh, %ls);        #Code copied from CPAN Net::OpenSSH
my @hosts = qw(host1 host2 host3 host4 );
 # multiple connections are stablished in parallel:
  for my $host (@hosts) {
  $ssh{$host} = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, async => 1); 
  $ssh{$host}->error and die "no remote connection "; <--- doesn't work here! :-(  
  }
# then to run some command in all the hosts (sequentially):
 for my $host (@hosts) {
 $ssh{$host}->system('ls /');
}
```

$ssh{$host}->error and die "no remote connection doesn't work".

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Consider using [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel). It takes care of all these low level details for you!

Answer (score 1):

You run async connections. So program continue work and dont wait when connection is establised.
After *new* with *async* option you try to check error but it is not defined because connection in progress and no information about error.

As i understand you need wait after first loop until connection process got results.

Try to use ->wait_for_master(0);

> If a false value is given, it will finalize the connection process and wait until the multiplexing socket is available.
>
> It returns a true value after the connection has been succesfully established. False is returned if the connection process fails or if it has not yet completed (then, the "error" method can be used to distinguish between both cases).

```
for my $host (@hosts) {
    $ssh{$host} = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, async => 1); 
}

for my $host (@hosts) {
    unless ($ssh{$host}->wait_for_master(0)) {
        # check $ssh{$host}->error  here. For example delete $ssh{$host}
    }
}

# Do work here
```

I don't check this code.

PS: Sorry for my English. Hope it helps you.

Comment: wait_for_master(0) is not working.It aborts the master ssh connection!

Comment: @Alex: wait_for_master should work. If it fails, check that the connection parameters are correct by connecting without the async flag.